# jsf fill title (tooltip) with line-break based on backing-bean

Tags: jsf, escaping, tooltip

So I dynamically generate a input form from backing bean.  One of the dynamically generated element is an image with title value (tooltip).  But I couldn't figure out how to add line-break into the title.

I tried `"\r\n", "<br/>", "&#013;"`, all end up showing the same value on the tooltip.

I know if it is an outputText, I could call escape="false" to make it work...but how to do it with the title field?

`<img src="img/info.png" title="#{bean.info}"/>`

wherea **bean.info** has value of

`"A : apple&#13;B : ball"`

but the tooltip end up showing `"A : apple&#13;B : ball"` instead of on two lines.

Or does anyone have idea how to put an outputText result into the title of an img tag?

Comment: Did just `\n` really not work? Did you make sure you didn't accidentally double-escape it as in `\\n`? The `&#013;` indeed won't work as Facelets XML-escapes it to `&amp;#013;` as part of XSS attack prevention. The `<br>` doesn't make sense as tooltips don't support HTML in first place.

Comment: I just tried adding `\n`, and the `\n` is completely removed...ie `info="abc\ndef"`, the output end up with `"abc def"`

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using? Can't reproduce with latest Mojarra (which is 2.2.12).

Comment: Yes, I'm still using an old implementation JSF 1.2 with Richfaces 3.3 (Mojarra 1.2_15).  In parallel, we're upgrading to JSF 2 and Richfaces 4, but there are so much changes so it take time.  

In the meantime, I'm trying the Tooltip tag from richfaces, its more code, but seems like an alternative as I can escape <br/> in the text.